# Linux - Run script after time period expires

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, scripting

I have a small NodeJS script that does some processing. Depending on the amount of data needing to be processed, this can take a couple of seconds to hours.

What I want is to do is schedule this command to run every hour after the previous attempt has completed. I'm wary of using something like cron because I need to ensure that two instances of the script aren't running at the same.

Comment: Use cron in combination with file system locking. The process checks if a lock file already exists. If so it terminates, if not it creates one and then starts its processing task. When finished it removes the lock file again. Extra points of the lock file contains the process ID of the process that created it. This allows a cleanup job to remove crashed jobs.

Comment: You can use cron + flock:

see http://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running

Comment: Use `at` at the end of your script to schedule the next run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't like *cron* (or *at*) you can just use a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    #Do something
    echo Invoke long-running node.js script

    #Wait an hour
    sleep 3600
done
```

The (obvious) drawback is that you will have to make it run in background somehow (i.e. via *nohup* or *screen*) and add a proper error handling (taking that you script might fail, and you still want it to run again in an hour).

A bit more elaborate "custom script" solution might be like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Settings
LAST_RUN_FILE=/var/run/lock/hourly.timestamp
FLOCK_LOCK_FILE=/var/run/lock/hourly.lock
FLOCK_FD=100

#Minimum time to wait between two job runs
MIN_DELAY=3600

#Welcome message, parameter check
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "Please specify the command (job) to run, as follows:"
    echo "./hourly COMMAND"
    exit 1
fi

echo "[$(date)] MIN_DELAY=$MIN_DELAY seconds, JOB=$@"

#Set an exclusive lock, or skip execution if it is already set
eval "exec $FLOCK_FD>$FLOCK_LOCK_FILE"
if ! flock -n $FLOCK_FD 
then
    echo "Lock is already set, skipping execution."
    exit 0
fi

#Last run timestamp
if ! [ -e $LAST_RUN_FILE ] 
then
    echo "Timestamp file ($LAST_RUN_FILE) is missing, creating a new one."
    echo 0 >$LAST_RUN_FILE
fi

#Compute delay, and wait
let DELAY="$MIN_DELAY-($(date +%s)-$(cat $LAST_RUN_FILE))"
if [ $DELAY -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "Waiting for $DELAY seconds, before proceeding..."
    sleep $DELAY
fi

#Proceed with an actual task
echo "[$(date)] Running the task..."
echo
"$@"

#Update the last run timestamp
echo
echo "Done, going to update the last run timestamp now."
date +%s >$LAST_RUN_FILE
```

This will do 2 things:

- Set an exclusive execution lock (with *flock*), so that no two instances of the job will run at the same time, irregardless of how you start them (manually or via *cron* e.t.c.);
- If the last job was completed less then *MIN_DELAY* seconds ago,
  it will sleep for the remaining time, before running the job again;

Now, if you schedule this script to run, say every 15 minutes with *cron*, like that:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/hourly my_periodic_task and it's arguments
```

It will be guaranteed to execute with the fixed delay of at least *MIN_DELAY* (one hour) since the last job completed, and any intermediate runs will be skipped.

In the worst case, it will execute in *MIN_DELAY* + 15 minutes,
(as the scheduling period is discrete), but never earlier than that.

Other non-*cron* scheduling methods should work too (i.e. just running this script in a loop, or re-scheduling and each run with *at*).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron and add `process.exit(0)` to your node script